# Does `diskpart clean` send a TRIM command?

Tags: windows, ssd, diskpart

If I have a full SSD and clean it with `diskpart clean`, will the SSD controller receive a TRIM command (assuming I'm running in AHCI mode)? This would be crucial for performance or even healthiness of the SSD because otherwise it wouldn't know that all data is invalid and can be overwritten at will.

I'm writing this out of suspicion it doesn't get a TRIM because I have ruined two Surface Pros so far while testing a reimaging process that involves a clean command. The devices got ever slower and at some time stopped working altogether. A missing TRIM would be consistent with this behavior.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`diskpart clean` only overwrites the MBR or GPT areas. It does not TRIM the entire drive.

I'm not aware of any utilities for Windows that can TRIM an entire drive. There are quite a few options for linux. `blkdiscard` is probably the easiest to use. `hdparam --trim-sector-ranges` is also an option.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. May I ask where you picked up that knowledge? I would be interested to learn more in this area.

Answer (score 4):

Adding to @longneck's answer:

`Optimize-Volume -DriveLetter <YourDriveLetter> -ReTrim -Verbose`

should be what you are looking for in Windows PowerShell,

`defrag <YourVolume> /L`

> Perform retrim on the specified volumes.

in Windows-Not-PowerShell.